# Continuity of the maximum of a function in two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

The function  $f( x, y)$ is continuous on $x\in [a,b]$,  $y\in [a,b]$.

Is the function $g(x) = \max_{y} f( x, y)$ continuous on  $x\in [a,b]$?

Answer (score 0):

***Hints:***

- Continuous functions on closed bounded intervals are bounded and hence $g(x)$ exists.
- Say, $g(x) = c$. What is the nature of the function on $[a, b]$. Rewrite the equation with $c$ and make a call.