# Continuity of the locus of the maximum of a two variables real function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose that $$\begin{array}{lrcl}
f : & [0,1]^2 & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{R} \\
    & (x,y) & \longmapsto & f(x,y) \end{array}$$ is a continuous function and that for all $x \in [0,1]$ $$\max_{y \in [0,1]} f(x,y)$$ is reached at a unique point $g(x)$, i.e. $$\max_{y \in [0,1]} f(x,y)=f(x,g(x))$$

What can we say about $g$ continuity?

*Note: the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911988/continuity-of-the-maximum-of-a-function-in-two-variables) is related but different.*

Comment: Have you looked into Catastrophe theory, which was big in the 1970's and discussed this kind of thing? It categorizes the kinds of possible discontinuities of $g$. The kinds do depend on the dimensionality of the functions involved.

Comment: @Rory I only have a superficial knowledge of catastrophe theory. Just the name of "catastrophe theory" suggests that there exist cases where $g$ is not continuous! Can you point me to an example?

Comment: I'm afraid I studied catastrophe theory a *long* time ago and only at the superficial level. Much of what I knew came from the article "[Catastrophe Theory](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/catastrophe-theory/)" in the April 1976 issue of Scientific American. I thought Martin Gardner also wrote something on it but I can only find [this](http://www.nybooks.com/articles/archives/1978/jun/15/the-charms-of-catastrophe/).  I also found [this](http://opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/10/08/dangerous-intersection/?_r=0) on my computer as well as...

Comment: ... an old Quattro Pro for DOS file that I used for a simulation and now cannot open. The examples that come to my mind don't quite match the requirements of your problem, since they deal with relative extrema or the uniqueness of $g(x)$ is not always satisfied. Sorry I can't help you much more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g$ is indeed continuous (and the condition that for each $x$ the maximum
of $ f(x,y)$ is attained at a **unique point** $y$ is essential).

Let $g(x_0) = y_0$, i.e. $M := f(x_0, y_0) = \max_{y \in [0,1]} f(x_0,y$),
and let $\varepsilon > 0$.

$f(x_0, y)$  is strictly less than $M$ for $|y - y_0| \ge \varepsilon$
(because of the uniqueness condition). Since $f$ is continuous,
we can choose $a$, $b$, $c$ such that
$$
 f(x_0, y) \le a < b < c < M \text{ for } |y - y_0| \ge \varepsilon \, .
$$
Now the uniform continuity implies that there is a $\delta > 0$
such that
$$ \tag 1
 f(x, y) \le  b 
\text{ for } |x - x_0| < \delta, |y - y_0| \ge \varepsilon \, .
$$

On the other hand, the continuity of $f$ at $(x_0, y_0)$ implies
that there is a positive $\delta_1 < \delta$ such that
$$ \tag 2
 f(x, y_0) > c \text{ for }  |x - x_0| < \delta_1 \, .
$$

Now let $|x - x_0| < \delta_1$. From $(2)$ we see that the maximum
of $y \to f(x, y)$ is at least $c$, and from $(1)$ we see that
this maximum can not be attained for $|y - y_0| \ge \varepsilon$.
It follows that the maximum is attained for some $y$
with  $|y - y_0| < \varepsilon$.

In other words, 
$$
|g(x) - y_0| < \varepsilon  \text{ for }  |x - x_0| < \delta_1 \, .
$$

Comment: Thanks Martin. I was trying complex arguments to get  that "$f(x_0, y)$  is strictly less than $M$ for $|y - y_0| \ge \varepsilon$" but in fact it is pretty straight forward. $K=[0,1] \cap \{|y - y_0| \ge \varepsilon\}$ is compact. So $f(x_0,.)$ is reaching its maximum on $K$ and as the maximum is unique, it is strictly less than $M$.